# Add crisp chat to google chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am developing a Google Chrome extension and want to add Crisp chat to it.
The [tutorial](https://help.crisp.chat/en/article/how-to-add-a-live-chat-to-my-website-10wcj3l/) suggests adding the following link to my HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript">window.$crisp=[];window.CRISP_WEBSITE_ID="....";(function(){d=document;s=d.createElement("script");s.src="https://client.crisp.chat/l.js";s.async=1;d.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(s);})();</script>
```

When I did, I received such an error:

```
Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-x........./vg='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.
```

I wrote to crisp support, but there is no specific solution at the moment.
Does anyone have experience with it?

Comment: Inline scripts aren't allowed in extensions, so you'll need to use a separate js file that sets `window` stuff. It won't help with the external script which isn't allowed in ManifestV3 extensions either, so you'll need to patch document.createElement to ignore 'script' tag, bundle the remote files with your extension and load them explicitly via `<script src=`.